# How to install Ubuntu on HP Envy m6 notebook

Tags: system-installation

I downloaded the link from the Ubuntu website for 16.04 LTS but that didn't seem to do anything for me. What am I missing? I'm a real novice here so do I need to download it on a disk or USB drive or can I download it straight to my laptop?

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a live installation by either burning the ISO image to a dvd, or creating a bootable USB (some tools for that: rufus, YUMI, multiboot...). After that, you'll have to restart your computer and boot into your live installation. From there you will have to choose where to install Ubuntu on your hard drive. BE CAREFUL not to erase your entire disk (a warning of that does appear). You will need an ext3 or ext4 partition. Click install, restart, and enjoy.

These are somewhat vague steps into the matter, [here is a tutorial](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop) with images on doing it. In case you run into any sort of troubles, a quick search on this forum WILL have the answer. Otherwise, ask away.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [Wubi](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wubi), because you can "try out" Ubuntu without actually changing partition, or even create boot USB/DVD. It's a Windows program that let you download Ubuntu installation ISO, and then it walks you through baby steps.

[image]

Comment: Probably, HP Envy m6 notebook is a notebook with a pre-installed Windows 8 or 10. So your recommendation needs a [community supported Wubi version](https://github.com/hakuna-m/wubiuefi/wiki#releases). see [Wubi info](http://askubuntu.com/tags/wubi/info)

Answer (score 0):

You can download [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64 bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/ubuntu-16.04-desktop-amd64.iso)

from the link above. If you are on windows I recommend to use [Win32 Disk Imager](https://sourceforge.net/projects/win32diskimager/) To make bootable usb drive. Yes You can download ubuntu image straight from your system.